# How to return a `QObject`-derived class by value?

Tags: c++, qt

To improve code readability, I want to create an object inside a function an return it by value (I let the compiler the task of optimizing the memory).

If I have a regular class I can do the following:

```
MyClass myFunction01()
{
  MyClass theRegularObject;
  //do things
  return theRegularObject;
}
```

So in my code I can do:

```
MyClass myObject = myFunction01();
```

However, if MyClass is a QObject derived one (let's call it QObjDerivedClass), I get a compilation error:

```
QObjDerivedClass::QObjDerivedClass(const QObjDerivedClass &) : attempting to reference a deleted function.
```

I think that the problem resides in that the QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator [QObject Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator).

As possible solutions I think the following ones, but maybe I am missing a better one?

1.Create the object in main and pass the object as a reference to the function

```
void myFunction01(CMyClass &theObj) {//do things}

//In my program
CMyClass myObj;
myFunction01(myObj);
```

2.Create a dynamic object inside the function and return a pointer (a smart pointer?)

```
QSharedPointer<CMyClass> myFunction01()
{
  QSharedPointer<CMyClass> p_theObj(new CMyClass);            
  //do things
  return p_theObj;
}

//At my program
QSharedPointer<CMyClass> p_myObj = myFunction01();

//When p_myObj goes out of scope the CMyClass object will be deleted.
//WARNING: Very important not to set a parent when we create the CMyClass object. 
//Otherwise, we will have problems due to double deletion.
```

**Are there any better/other ideas?**

Comment: Or just use a plain pointer. This is what Qt usually does to `QObject`s. Please also check this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

Comment: You cannot return a polymorphic object by value, because you get object slicing. I'm sure that's why QObject doesn't have a copy constructor or assignment operator, to prevent you from trying something that won't work.

Comment: @MarkRansom, not really. `QObject` is neither copyable nor movable because other `QObject`s refer it via its address, e.g. in parent-child relationship or in signals and slots. Check out this: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49604

Comment: It's possible to implement move semantics for custom `QObject` subclasses that aren't widgets, with the natural limitation that none of your code can hold on to the object via a naked pointer as such a pointer would become invalid. `QPointer` would still work, of course. But since Qt itself only references `QObject`s internally in a few well known locations that the move constructor can fix up, it's possible to do it without patching Qt. I'll probably write up the solution I use at some point. It does the job. `QWidget` is too convoluted to become a movable class without changing Qt itself.

Comment: Also note that double deletion isn't a given. All you have to pay attention to is the guaranteed scoped object destruction order. It's in the C++ standard, so you can depend on it - lots of code would break if it didn't work :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By design, a `QObject` should never be passed by value.

> The Qt Object Model requires that we think of Qt Objects as identities, not values. Values are copied or assigned; identities are cloned ... Therefore, QObject and all subclasses of QObject (direct or indirect) have their copy constructor and assignment operator disabled. ([Source](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/object.html#identity-vs-value))

Because of this, your original example is inherently wrong. Instead you should be interacting with `QObject`s (and `QObject` derived classes) with pointers.

The standard practice with Qt is to allocate your objects on the heap using `new`. As long as the object has a proper parent, [it will be destroyed automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19332239/735425).

> All child objects are deleted. If any of these objects are on the stack or global, sooner or later your program will crash. ([Source](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#dtor.QObject))

This practice can be seen in official samples, such as [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-videowidget-videoplayer-cpp.html). The objects are explicitly allocated on the heap, and clean-up (`delete`) is left for the parent to handle.

So to summarize: Allocate your `QObject`-derived objects on the heap and pass them by pointers.

**Note:** If you would rather make use of a smart-pointer, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19346983/735425) has a good summary of those built into Qt.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was hoping not to use child-parent relationship for this case so I will use the smart-pointer approach.